# LeetCode Question: Improve Execution Time w/o Hash?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

My solution to find out if an integer is duplicated in an array, while correct, is getting rejected because the time limit LeetCode expects is exceeded. I understand that nested for loop is the culprit with an O(n^2). Is there a way to reduce this in any meaningful way without resorting to a hash?

```
bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize){
    
    bool result = 0;
    
    for( int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j < (numsSize - i); j++)
        {
            if(nums[i] == nums[i + j])
            {
                result = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can sort the array and see if any two consecutive values are same or not. It will solve the problem in O(nlogn)

Comment: use a Set and every time check if the element is already inserted (O(1)), and if not, insert it, otherwise you have a duplicate, so every iteration you do a O(1) operation, and you will do it at most n times, so you ends up with a O(n) solution (but you will consume at most O(n) memory, but seems like it's not a concern here)

Comment: How many items are in the array?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar sort an entire array to find a duplicate?..

Comment: I am suggesting a solution which doesn't use hash. Yes, it is not an efficient one.

Comment: Also as an optimization to your current solution, you can add a break statement after finding a duplicate. Of course, the complexity will remain the same.

Comment: @Berto99 std::set insert is O(log n) not O(1)

Comment: @HikmatFarhat nope, ordered_set has O(logn), but we don't need the order, so we can use `unordered_set` that has in average O(1)

Comment: @berto99 unordered_set is basically a hash table. I thought he didn't want to use one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [leetcode problem specifies](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-duplicate-number/) no more than 30001 numbers between 2 and 30000 in value; only one number will be duplicated one or more times.  We can make a 30001 sized array of unsigned char initialized to zeros, and then set an array val to 1 as we examine each one.  Further, we check to see if we've already seen it (set it to one) and bail if we have:

```
int containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize){
  int result = 0;
  unsigned char seenmap[30001] = {0};
  for( int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
  {
     if( seenmap[ nums[i] ] == 1 )
     {
       result = nums[i];
       break;
     } 
     seenmap[ nums[i] ] = 1;
  }
  return result;
}
```